# Why is a TypeBuilder generated generic methodinfo not a generic method?

Tags: c#, cil, reflection.emit, il

I have some code that uses a `MethodInfo` of a generic method found on a generated type. To avoid some reflection, I have the code use the

```
ldtoken Method
ldtoken Type
call GetMethodFromHandle(RuntimeMethodHandle,RunTimeTypeHandle)
```

Pattern to generate the MethodInfos at compile time.

However, if the methodInfo belongs to a generic type and itself is a generic method things get screwy. 
Here is some code that simply generates a GM that emits an open version of its methodInfo.
If I call it to retrieve the method than try to close it over a specific type I get a perplexing exception::

> System.Reflection.MethodInfo `GM[M]()` is not a GenericMethodDefinition. MakeGenericMethod may only be called on a method for which MethodBase.IsGenericMethodDefinition is true.

Here is the relevant code::

```
var aBuilder = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DefineDynamicAssembly(new AssemblyName("Test"), AssemblyBuilderAccess.RunAndSave);
var mBuilder = aBuilder.DefineDynamicModule(aBuilder.GetName().Name, true);
var typeBuilder = mBuilder.DefineType("NameSpace.Generic`1",TypeAttributes.AutoClass | TypeAttributes.Sealed | TypeAttributes.Public,typeof(object));
var TypeGenerics = typeBuilder.DefineGenericParameters(new[] { "T" });
var methodBuilder = typeBuilder.DefineMethod("GM", MethodAttributes.Public | MethodAttributes.Static | MethodAttributes.HideBySig);
var methodGenerics = methodBuilder.DefineGenericParameters(new[] { "M" });
methodBuilder.SetSignature(typeof(MethodInfo), null, null, Type.EmptyTypes, null, null);
var ilgenerator = methodBuilder.GetILGenerator();
var typeBuilderClosedOverT = typeBuilder.MakeGenericType(TypeGenerics);
ilgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, methodBuilder);
ilgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeBuilderClosedOverT);
ilgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Call, 
    typeof(MethodBase).GetMethod(
        "GetMethodFromHandle", 
        BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Static,
        null,
        new[] { typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle), typeof(RuntimeTypeHandle) },
        null
    )
);
ilgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Castclass,typeof(MethodInfo));
ilgenerator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var bakedType = typeBuilder.CreateType();
var methodInfo = bakedType.MakeGenericType(typeof(int)).GetMethod("GM").MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool)).Invoke(null, null) as MethodInfo;
var methodInfoClosedOverBool = methodInfo.MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool));
```

It seems the only time my code screws up is if it's a genericmethod on a non-generic type. If the code is rewritten so that its about a normal method on a normal type, or a generic method on a normal type, or a normal method on a generic type it all works. It's only the combination of both that causes errors. Am I doing something wrong?

I submitted a bug about this issue:
https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/775989/clr-cannot-emit-a-token-for-an-open-generic-method-on-a-generic-type

Comment: That's interesting, it looks like `methodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition` is indeed `false`, although `methodInfo.GetGenericArguments()` returns a type that is generic parameter.

Comment: Yeah inspecting it certainly makes it look like the damn thing is generic. My current solution is to make sure my methods have unique names and passing in the `Type` and a `string`, and calling `type.GetMethod(...)`, but I'd like to avoid the reflection.

Comment: Seems that it is now resolved in .net 4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a CLR issue to me, because the same thing happens if you write the IL by hand and use ilasm.  That is, given a generic class `G` and a nongeneric class `N`, each with a generic method `M`, then trying to get the generic method definition from the non-generic class works:

```
ldtoken    method void class N::M<[1]>()
ldtoken    class N<!T>
call       class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodBase [mscorlib]
             System.Reflection.MethodBase::GetMethodFromHandle(
                valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeMethodHandle,
                valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
castclass  [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo
ret
```

but the `MethodInfo` returned from the generic class is not a generic method definition (but it almost is; it's `D.MakeGenericMethod(D.GetGenericArguments())` where `D` is the method definition you want):

```
ldtoken    method void class G`1<!T>::M<[1]>()
ldtoken    class G`1<!T>
call       class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodBase [mscorlib]
             System.Reflection.MethodBase::GetMethodFromHandle(
                valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeMethodHandle,
                valuetype [mscorlib]System.RuntimeTypeHandle)
castclass  [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo
ret
```

Comment: Well thanks I actually just did the same thing with concrete types (List<int>.ConvertAll) and I'm going to report this as a bug to microsoft. I doubt much will happen :(

Comment: What's interesting is that this IL cannot be compiled back: "error : syntax error at token '['"

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies within the `ldtoken method` instruction because, due to the inability of IL to express generic method definitions, the CLR loads the wrong method. The instruction is decompiled by ildasm to this:

```
ldtoken method class [mscorlib]System.Reflection.MethodInfo class NameSpace.Generic`1<!T>::GM<[1]>()
```

Which isn't even valid IL. The CLR then messes up the instruction and instead loads a generic method instantiation from it's own generic parameters.

```
var methodInfoClosedOverBool = (methodInfo.IsGenericMethodDefinition ? methodInfo : methodInfo.GetGenericMethodDefinition()).MakeGenericMethod(typeof(bool));
```

For more tests, I've made a shorter code showing the same issue:

```
DynamicMethod dyn = new DynamicMethod("", typeof(RuntimeMethodHandle), null);
var il = dyn.GetILGenerator();
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ldtoken, typeof(GenClass<string>).GetMethod("GenMethod"));
il.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
var handle = (RuntimeMethodHandle)dyn.Invoke(null, null);
var m = MethodBase.GetMethodFromHandle(handle, typeof(GenClass<int>).TypeHandle);
```

`GetMethodFromHandle` (which should also only require the method handle, not the declaring type) just sets the declaring type (notice `<int>` or `<string>` doesn't matter) and doesn't do anything wrong.